# Hide Moodle Default Login Page and use OAuth2 Authentication only

Tags: oauth-2.0, moodle

I have configured the authentication with OAuth 2 service and it does appear on the Moodle Login page, but now I would like to have only OAuth2 authentication and redirect back to Moodle site. May I know how should I proceed? I have tried to make changes to the login page and directly redirect to OAuth2 authentication page with redirect() function, but after I pressed on the Login button it kept redirecting me to OAuth issuer site and then Moodle oauth2callback.php as shown in the screenshot below. or is there any available plugin for the implementation?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your config.php

```
$CFG->alternateloginurl=<Your Custom Login URL>;
```